# Is there a website to compare font prices?

Tags: fonts, resource-recommendations

Most commercial fonts are available on different websites for different prices. Is there a webservice that compares those prices and displays the cheapest price for a specific font?

Comment: Sometimes the foundry gives a better deal than a third-party site, but I haven’t seen many differences in price.  When I think I’ve found a better price, closer inspection often reveals that it’s not the very same font: some sites don’t make it obvious to casual visitors that they’re selling the standard rather than the pro version.

Comment: Problem with font prices is that in different countries there are taxes and fonts are treated like software (or not) and the same foundry can have different price depending on the currency you want to buy.  So looking at font made in UE and buying it in UE, the price could be totally different than buying it in US.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you asked for, but [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/) will tell you the various different online stores any given font can be purchased from including purchase links - from there it should be just a click-through to see prices.